How to avoid calculation of a duplicate subsidy when there is a bundle product in WooCommerce cart?
With the code below, I calculate and displays the total subsidies amount based on cart item shipping class and quantity:
/**
 * Utility function: Get shipping class subsidy amount
 * 
 * @return float
 */
function get_shipping_class_subsidy_amount( $shipping_class ) {
    // return a float number for '12-50' case
    if ( false !== strpos($shipping_class, '12-50') ) {
        return 12.5;
    }
    // Extract the integer from the slug
    else {
        return preg_replace('/\D/', '',  $shipping_class);
    }
}

/**
 * Utility function: Get total subsidies amount
 * 
 * @return float
 */
function get_total_subsidies( $cart_items ){
    $total_subsidy = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart_items as $item ){
        $subsidy = (float) get_shipping_class_subsidy_amount( $item['data']->get_shipping_class() );
        $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
        if ( $subsidy > 0 ) {
            $total_subsidy += $item['quantity'] * $subsidy;
        }
    }
    return $total_subsidy;
}


/**
 * Display HTML formatted total subsidies amount in classic cart and checkout pages.
 * Hooked function.
 */
function display_total_subsidies() {
    if ( $total_subsidy = get_total_subsidies( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) ) {
        echo '<tr class="subsidies">
            <th>' . esc_html__( 'Subsidies', 'woocommerce' ) . '</th>
            <td data-title="' . esc_html__( 'Subsidies', 'woocommerce' ) . '">' . wc_price($total_subsidy) . '</td>
        </tr>';
    }
}

add_action ( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping', 'display_total_subsidies', 10 ); // for Cart page
add_action ( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping', 'display_total_subsidies', 10 ); // for Checkout page

The problem is that the cart item subsidy amount is obtained twice when it's a bundle product, as it takes into account the bundled product itself and it's products components.
But the calculation in the label is correct.

Edit:
Below, the first screenshot shows the result with no subsidy amount.
The second one shows the subsidy with 12.5 for the individual items that should not be taken into account and 80 for the complete bundle. Here the subsidy is incorrect because it is taking into account each individual component (item) of the bundle and the complete bundle subsidy, but the rate calculation is correct because it just takes into account the complete bundle.
No subsidy:

Individual components (items) and complete bundle product subsidy:


Your question is not clear: How is the calculation in the label is correct? Can you edit your question and give a concrete example that illustrate the issue, maybe using some screenshots?

Do you think The screenshots and explanation are clear now?

So what is wrong is the displayed Subsidies amount (that sum the main bundle (80) and each of the 6 components (6 x 12.5 = 75) which makes 155, instead of only 80)... It is very strange that the rate calculation is correct, as you are using the same calculation code for both. Sorry, I don't have any clue, to solve this issue.

Yes, thats the point and I think the same, I do not know what is happening.f the fuction is called bye the addaction why is different calculation...

Bundle products in WC are treated as separate line items for both the parent bundle and its individual components, which means that in the current loop in the get_total_subsidies function may double-count the subsidy for bundled products.
You can try to apply the subsidy calculation to the child components of a bundle to your code.
function get_total_subsidies( $cart_items ){
    $total_subsidy = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart_items as $item_key => $item ){
        // Skip child items of bundled products
        if ( isset( $item['bundled_by'] ) && ! empty( $item['bundled_by'] ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $subsidy = (float) get_shipping_class_subsidy_amount( $item['data']->get_shipping_class() );

        if ( $subsidy > 0 ) {
            $total_subsidy += $item['quantity'] * $subsidy;
        }
    }
    return $total_subsidy;
}


But the point with this is that some individual bundle component child have diferente amount subsidy than the bundle, I need the calculation skip the individual bundle and get the result of the bundle as complete product. Besides the block of code to get the subsidy does it fine, the problem y that the displaying is wrong.
